# How to display a GUI text at run time in unity?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I'd like to display a GUI text at run time in my game for a second, so I want to know if it's possible to add or remove a GUI label to the scene at run time?

Comment: Sure you can do that. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- start a coroutine, which first waits for 1 second, and then set a boolean member variable to true (which initially is false)
- in OnGUI => if the bool is true show the Label

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
void OnGUI() {
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10f, 10f, 100f, 50f), "YourText");
}
```

Or, in UnityScript (basically the same):

```
function OnGUI() {
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10f, 10f, 100f, 50f), "YourText");
}
```

Comment: :no I want this to be happened at a specific time at run time

Comment: @Akari Then you might want to check [`realTimeSinceStartup`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) to determine whether it should show the text.